# Python, возвращает из DB postgresql, не корретные данные

Tags: python

При отправке запроса в БД через питон

```
import psycopg2 as pg_driver
db = pg_driver.connect(user=var_user, password=var_password, host=var_host, 
port=var_port)
cursor = db.cursor()
sql_query = ("""select * 
from asset_dhcp
where id = 1""")
cursor.execute(sql_query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
db.close()
print(result)
```

Получаю ответ из бд в виде такой вот штуки:

```
[(1L, '00:50:56:ba:50:16', 131772604591350070L)]
```

Хотя в самой бд значения 1, 00:50:56:ba:50:16, 131772604591350070

БД имеет кодировку utf-8

Comment: Все корректно. 1L = 1, но третий питон возможно поругается.

Comment: Тогда как избавиться от этого L? Для того что бы вывод из селекта использовать...

Comment: Питон какой версии?

Comment: Версия python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

`L` после числа означает, что число в формате long. Перевести его в "обычный" формат (`int`) в Python 2.x очень просто:

```
x = int(x)
```

---

*С версиями 3.x будут проблемы, там объединили `int` и `long`; и `long` отсутствует. Так что значение 1L даже не получится присвоить какой-нибудь переменной, будет синтаксическая ошибка. Поэтому придется решать проблему другим образом (настройками ДБ или еще как).*